# How to generate access token for OAuth authentication using the available Client ID and Client Secret for GMail API (IMAP)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I have generated a Client ID and Client Secret for my application using the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) for my Java web application.

I want to generate an `access token` to be used in my application to authenticate a mailbox and read mails from there with the help of JavaMail API.

[This link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?csw=1) has some theoretical information but I could not understand how the tokens can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Answer will depend upon where is application running as it determines how access token can be received:

- Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications
- OAuth 2.0 for Client-side
- Web Applications OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps
- OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications

There are different alternatives or libraries available to get access token depending upon the type of application and different specific mechanisms are defined around it.

So it will be then much easier to dive-in into the specific options available.

Comment: Thanks. Like I've mentioned, the said application is a Java web application. Could you guide or provide insights based on this?

Comment: Assuming that installed app is running on Android then it must open the system browser using intents and supply a local redirect URI to handle responses from Google's authorization server. For this in your app you need to web server bound to local port so that access tokens can be delivered to your app. Once your app has received access token then it can use the same along with GMail API. Alternatively: Use Google Sign-in client libraries available on Android/iOS to handle authentication and user authorization.

Comment: It is not a Mobile application but a web application.